# How can I add Language Switching button in Big Commerce header?

Tags: bigcommerce, multilingual

I have setup two languages json files(en.json and fr-CA.json) and work perfectly if I switch the language locale preference in the browser. But Need a help to add an explicit language switching button in the header. How can i achieve this without using third party language switcher plugins?